# Postgres CASE expression then null

Tags: postgresql, case

The below query is part of a select query which I have got in my application

```
where 
case when o.tracking_id <> '0' then a.account_id is null
and 
o.status = 'N'

else
(

o.tracking_id = '0'
and 
o.status = 'N'

)
END
```

I am having hardtime to understand the below line

Can you please tell me what does this exactly mean ?

```
case when o.tracking_id <> '0' then a.account_id is null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use a `CASE` expression here but instead would use the following logic:

```sql
WHERE
    (o.tracking_id <> '0' AND a.account_id IS NULL AND o.status = 'N')
    OR
    (o.tracking_id = '0' AND o.status = 'N')
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition is written somewhat clumsily. It is equivalent to this more readable expression:

```sql
where (o.tracking_id = '0' or a.account is null)
and o.status = 'N';
```